# VBA sort function not working

Tags: vba, sorting

The following is an excerpt from a larger section of VBA code. I'm having a problem sorting a list of values after I paste them from another sheet. The list of values are successfully pasted and are selected before the sorting should be happening. Also the sorting code which I'm using works fine if it's used seperately in a macro by itself. Any suggestions as to what may be going wrong here? Thanks

```
Dim ProductType As String
Dim ValueDate As String
ProductType = Range("I19").value
ValueDate = Range("I18").value

ActiveSheet.name = ProductType & " " & ValueDate

Sheets("SensitivityResults").Cells(6, 1).Resize(653).Copy
Sheets(ProductType & " " & ValueDate).Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
```

Answer (score 0):

selection might not be set properly, try with

```
Sheets(ProductType & " " & ValueDate).Range("A3:A656").Sort Key1:=Range("A3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
```